# Is there a maximum HTTP status code message length?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, http-status-codes

I'm working on a project where I'm building the frontend and someone else is building an API. I was proposing the following structure for all requests, sent as JSON:

```
{
  "success": true, // true/false
  "message": null, // a string if success==false indicating the error
  "data": {} // The actual data in the response
}
```

They are more interested in making the API more RESTful, and instead of a "message" field they are proposing sending a message back in the status code message, in the HTTP headers, such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication Failed for john.smith@example.com. Please log in again.
```

and the frontend would display "Authentication Failed for john.smith@example.com. Please log in again." in a popup or something.

I'm worried about length restrictions, but I couldn't find anything indicating no maximum length. Should we ensure we keep those messages to a minimum length? Is there a good reason to not do this, and instead send it back as content (JSON or plain text)?

Comment: In my tests with IIS Express and Google Chrome, I got `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` errors when having a too long error message and/or having line breaks contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little testing will go a long way, but you should be okay to do this and in fact the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1) says specifically:

> The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.

The only possible concern you may have is header size (some servers may have limitations, but I think they are all relatively large) and how some older browsers may react to this.  Frankly I think it makes more sense to use the response body since it's easier to interpret and clear, but there shouldn't be anything wrong with your approach.

Comment: FYI, RFC 2616 has been superceded last month by RFC 7231 through 7235. RFC 7230 specifies length requirements for various elements, although not the `reason-phrase` in a status response.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add, although there might be no limit in the specification, there is a real chance of implementations to truncate the status message, as I discovered, when I was trying something similar as the OP with Jetty 9.4.14 .

It took me some time to find the reason for the truncated message - there is a hard coded, not configurable limit of 1024 characters [see method [getReasonBytes(String)](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpGenerator.java#LC600)].

*(could not post this as comment due to lack of reputation)*