# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, http, reset

I have a PHP scripts that downloads and process some files. Sometimes the number of files is very large, so it takes some time.

But when there are a lot of files to process, the connection interrupts with a "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error (Chrome).

Here's my configuration:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = -1
memory_limit = 512M
```

I have a shared hostind. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are too many files to process, you'll eventually stumble upon this issue whatever your configuration. Even if you disable all timeouts server-side, the client itself has its own safety features and will eventually timeout after a certain time — something you can't control.

“*You are doing it wrong*” here. You cannot do any heavy computation in a HTTP request because of this kind of protocol limitations (TCP, HTTP).

Your request has to spawn some kind of **background task** that will notify of its progress from time to time. Using a shared hosting with PHP only, this might not be easy to accomplish, so you may want to find another way of doing your heavy computation.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try a different approach.

Comment: I think I have come across this same issue. My form seems to be timing out but only in Chrome, Windows 10. I'm using a single AJAX request but I am doing some heavy lifting. Would the solution be to split the requests into two? Adding another request doesn't sound right, but I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: @MichaelLynch just spawn/register some background task and instantly redirect the user to some "please wait" page. This page either reloads itself every few seconds or uses JS to retrieve the task completion status. When the task is done, redirect it to the actual result page you would have shown in the first place. There is no good way to fight against timeouts, just embrace them.

Comment: @zopieux by "some kind of background task" are you referring to using PHP to run system commands (e.g. using system())?

Answer (score 11):

`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` usually means that the connection to the server has died without any responses to the client – not even some kind of HTTP 5xx error. This means that the entire PHP process has died without being able to shut down properly.

This is usually *not* caused by something like an exceeded memory_limit, because that's something PHP would handle gracefully. This must be some sort of Segmentation Fault or similar. If you have access to error logs, check them. Otherwise, you might get support from your hosting company.

Comment: Your answer is more accurate - this is likely a seg-fault, not out-of-memory. So what kind of log would one look at? In my case neither the PHP log nor the Apache log contain any entries at the time of the fault.

Comment: Depends on how you run PHP. If it’s Apache + mod_php, the Apache logs. If it’s PHP-FPM, then the FPMs own error logging. If you can’t find an entry, you may need to increase the log level. ON FPM, you must also set `catch_workers_output = yes` (but only in your DEV environment!).

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning cookies resolved it when I had this issue on `Google chrome`

Comment: Your answer was flagged because of its length and content. I suggest revising. Perhaps add additional details.

Answer (score 0):

On my IIS server with ASP.NET MVC, I accidentially generated the `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error in Google Chrome due to the fact that my HTTP status code description contained new line characters (`\r\n`).

I. e. this would generate the error:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.StatusDescription = "This is a status code\r\nwith newline.";

    return View();
}
```

To resolve it, I simply removed the newline characters.

Another issue *may* be that the status code description is [too long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24537159/107625).