# in PHP call a function to return large array, get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, arrays

currently in the php, I call a function which return large array(around 3500*float),I got the error ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. (it is localhost environment)

I checked the log file, it showes:

```
[Wed Apr 29 08:10:24.250904 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2920:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Apr 29 08:10:24.391529 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2920:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Apr 29 08:10:24.422779 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2920:tid 260] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I also checked ports 443 and 80 which are not used by others. 
if I change that function to return a smaller array, this error will go away.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: How much memory is allocated to PHP? Have you tried watching `top` while running the function?

Comment: I checked the php.ini, it looks like 128M

Comment: Answered Already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378703/err-connection-reset-with-php-script

Comment: thanks. I will give a try to see if I can try a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You should change allow memori size

In your php.ini file  if you are sure the problem is about memori size but the problem does not look memori size

Please write your array and page code to help you !
Find 
`allow_memori_size=`

Comment: yes. it looks like not a memory size problem. but that function is from a COM object,

Comment: Route::get('/test', function(){
 $wrap = new COM('wraplib.Class1');
 
 $p = $wrap->getPoints();
});

Comment: Be sure your class name does not return the same Classic name !

Comment: sorry but what you mean:   "your class name does not return the same Classic name"

Comment: For example my class make too much process and if i call the same class in one page two Times it can make the server tired also if i return the class name for example <code>class a { pıblic function b(){ $aa=new a(); return $aa;}. </code> Also Over than once return can make the Server tired

Comment: Sorry about spelling mistakes i am texting on phone

Comment: He is trying to say: Make sure, when you have a class that utilizes a lot of memory/processing power, that your methods return either data or the class itself and not an instance of a new class of the exact same type. 

ie:
`return $this;` or `return $data` but not `return (new COM)`

Comment: I didn't return new COM(). In the routing function, It just call "new COM()" to create a COM object, then call that function  from the COM object. I am confused is it looks like my php script is never get executed.