# Error net :: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in upload of files with AJAX request. Any solution?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using a file type input to create a directory upload page.

Directory upload is done through a POST AJAX request.

The problem is that when I try to upload a very large directory, it fails showing the following error:

> net :: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

The state of the jqXHR object is 0.

Comment: What is the actual HTTP response code - probably a 500? If so, then go check the server’s error logs first of all. Likely one of the usual problems with some PHP configuration limit relevant to file uploads being to low. (Please _research_ which the most relevant are, if you have no clue, and check what they are set to.)

Comment: it may happen when you exceed your server execution time or size of memory. check your server configuration and set it to max

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378703/err-connection-reset-with-php-script

this thread saying that you cant do heavy computations using https. please read this also.